# Getting point values within a rotated UIView (iOS)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, bounds

I am trying to rotate an image, and trying to limit the available space to be tapped. How can I return the location within a rotated view's boundaries so I can compare the tapped location to the available locations?

Ex:

```
if ([touch locationInView:self].y > 320.0) {
        return [super beginTrackingWithTouch:touch withEvent:event];
    }
```

How can I convert the value from locationInView so I will always check the same location within UIView's bounds, instead of the frame?

Comment: So you want the rotated point? Or you don't want a rotated point?

Comment: I want to be able to get the touched point value from bounds instead of frame, so it will be the same whether it's rotated or not. Or convert the [touch locationInView:] value to the value within the bounds.

Comment: I think you misunderstand bounds and frame... So would NSPointInRect(view.frame) work? (point is in superview coordinates)

Comment: Maybe. But that seems to be returning a BOOL. I'd like to compare it to a smaller value within the view.